# Make a Perl object callable?

Tags: perl

In Perl 5, is there a way to make an object callable?

**Example.pm**

```
package Example;
use strict;
use warnings;
sub new {
    my ($class) = @_;
    my $self = {};
    bless($self, $class);
    return $self;
}

# implement function to make class callable

1;
```

**main.pl**

```
use Example;
my $ex = Example->new();
my $ex(); # call the object like this
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by blessing a function reference instead of a hash reference to create the class.

For example:

**Example.pm:**

```
package Example;
use strict;
use warnings;
sub new {
    my ($class) = @_;
    my $self = \&call;
    bless($self, $class);
    return $self;
}

# implement function to make class callable
sub call {
    print "Calling the function\n";
}

1;
```

**main.pl:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Example;

my $ex = Example->new();
$ex->();
```

**Output:**

> Calling the function

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to simply call `$ex` with `$ex()` as opposed to `$ex->()`?

Comment: I don't think so. As far as I know, classes are always stored as a reference so you need to use the dereference operator `->` in order to access the class data.

Comment: Or you can do `&$ex()` but I don't think that looks any better IMHO and also makes the assumption that $ex is a function ref.

Comment: @tjwrona1992, Your `new` always returns the same object. Also, you don't explain how to give attributes to your object, which is quite [complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44957490/589924).

Comment: @aoiee, Re "*Is there a way to simply call `$ex` with `$ex()` as opposed to `$ex->()`*", You can make reading from `$ex` call a sub, but then you wouldn't be able to pass arguments to the sub, and you wouldn't be able to assign to the object to any other var. /// `$ex()` is not a sub call; it's not even valid Perl syntax. /// You could make `$$ex` call a sub, but you wouldn't be able to pass arguments to the sub.

Comment: @ikegami, yes it's true that in my example it will return the same object every time and does not allow attributes. Thank you for the clarification and link to more information.