# Why is the refcount for a sub higher than for an array?

Tags: perl

I have this test program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Devel::Refcount qw( refcount );
my $subref = sub {1};
printf "\$subref has REFCNT=%d\n", refcount( $subref );
my $arrayref = [];
printf "\$arrayref has REFCNT=%d\n", refcount( $arrayref );
```

**Output**:

```
$subref has REFCNT=2
$arrayref has REFCNT=1
```

Why is the reference count for the `sub` 2 (I expected it to be 1 as for the array ref)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case where a closure isn't involved (i.e. the sub doesn't refer to any outer lexical variables), perl optimises things by sharing the sub (CV) rather than cloning it. So the first ref is for the "prototype" sub created at compile time, with an additional ref for each $subref created at runtime (an RV pointing at the original CV).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44957490/589924) for code that has to work around this optimization :)